# Scheduling multiple tasks using timers

Tags: java

How can I schedule multiple tasks using [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). I want to read multiple files using timers. I think I have to give each file a different `TimerTask` so that one file gets one instance of `TimerTask` and other file gets another, but I don't know how to do it. Please help. Thanks in advance. Here is what I'm doing:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    // repeat the check every second
    timer.schedule(fileWatcherTask, new Date(), 1000);
```

Comment: do you want to read the file right now or some time later? do you already know the file names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) of Timer class indicates your tasks should take very few time. In this case you can forget about time clash. If your tasks take more then 0.1 seconds run them in separate thread. I mean use Timer as a trigger that just makes task to start in separate thread.

**you can also use quartz scheduler for that refer** http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/

if you want to use timer class see the example in following image [image]

refer [link for more details](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=rl6SFYAdL6YC&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=using%20timer%20class%20for%20multithreading%20example%20java&source=bl&ots=7KA-61Fq-6&sig=EMk6AdavtXPVvePj_2aAgiNwq4k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A4onT_iTEsjsrAeEx73jAQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)